# Why is this Joomla template not working?

Tags: templates, joomla

I just installed Joomla on my pc. Everything works just fine. I installed a lot of templates and they all worked, but the template i really want to use doesn't.

I want to use this template: http: //byjoomla.com/docman/bj-joomla-templates/bj-venus/download.html
The result would have to be like [this](http://byjoomla.com/venus/).

When I installed Joomla i clicked on the button "Install Sample Data". When i install the template i get this error on a blank page:

```
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\html\com_content\frontpage\default_item.php on line 158
```

When i don't install the sample data, the template is displayed, but it contains a lot of errors.
Take a look: http: //grab.by/6eGi

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant _ISO - assumed '_ISO' in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 20
```

> Deprecated: Function split() is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php
>   on line 20

```
Notice: Undefined variable: header in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 98

Notice: Undefined variable: toolbar in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 1

Notice: Undefined variable: advert1 in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 131

Notice: Undefined variable: headline in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 138

Notice: Undefined variable: top in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 152

Notice: Undefined variable: right in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined variable: banner in C:\wamp\www\templates\bj_venus\index.php on line 166
```

I don't know what's wrong. I've opened a topic at the official Joomla-forums, but i don't get any answer: http:// forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=466&p=2250353

// Sorry about the space between http:// and the other part, but that's because i'm not allowed to post more hyperlinks... (I have to gain 10 reputation points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your PHP correctly. If everything is configured right and you are getting error, then the template is buggy. I looked at the `bj_venus\html\com_content\frontpage\default_item.php`, the file looks fine, no errors... most likely config problem.

Joomla runs under following requirements, http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

1. Make sure you are **not running PHP 5.3**, Joomla is does not run on PHP 5.3 well (a lot of bugs). You need PHP 5.2.x
2. Disable error reporting, but modifying **php.ini** set `display_errors = Off` to hide all the errors. Or if you are developing and want to ignore notices set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` - this will display errors but ignore notices. For more error reporting configuration see [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

Answer (score 1):

Go into your global settings and make sure under the Server tab, that Error Reporting is set to none. I noticed I had some of these errors on that same template when I turned it on, but when I set it back to none it cleared them up. Hope this works.